# "Кузькина мать"

Tags: фразеология

Вопрос, навершеное, совершенно банальный, но все-таки, кто такая эта "Кузькина мать", которую в известной поговорке обещают показать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Версий о происхождении этого фразеологизма существует немало (см., например, в Википедии). Из наиболее достоверных можно назвать следующие.
По одной из версий, Кузька — это наименование плётки как орудия домашнего наказания, которую жених клал в сапог в день свадьбы «на Кузьминки» как символ супружеской власти. Святые Косма и Дамиан считались в русской культуре покровителями свадеб.
Кстати, с днем Козьмы и Дамиана ("кузьминками", "кузьками"), которых поминали 1 ноября, связано выражение «подкузьмить», что обозначало обман в соглашении, заключённом до традиционного первоноябрьского срока, то есть своеобразную расплату за невнимание к традиции.

По другой версии, Кузьмой называли проказливого и бестолкового домового. А его невидимке-матушке отводили место обитания рядом с потопком — за печью. Но, как считалось, уж если она покажется кому из проживающих в избе, то непременно напугает.

Некоторые исследователи (например, Сергеев В.Н.) полагали, что «Кузькина мать» — реально существовавшая женщина, со временем превратившаяся в персонаж народных фразеологизмов. По всей видимости, матерью некоего Кузьмы была очень злая и своенравная женщина, встреча с которой была большим испытанием для человека. Поэтому, угроза «показать мать Кузьмы (Кузькину мать)» имеет целью напугать человека разборками с неким властным человеком.

Еще по одной версии, в некоторых финно-угорских языках (у коми-зырян, удмуртов) могло означать чёрта, лешего: скорее, это наиболее правильная версия, и ещё этот чёрт похож на козу или козла, так выражения «подкузьмить» и «подкозлить» равнозначны, аналогично как и «кузькина мать» и «чёртова мать».

Comment: Браво! Я о последней, козлиной, версии даже не слышал, а ведь когда-то пытался разбираться. Где вы её сыскали? Вышлядит очень и очень правдоподобно.

Comment: Да в Википедии и взяла :-)